# Is that the way to open old project in VS2008 without using any .NET framework?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008

I've got a question about opening the old project in VS2008.

If I have old c++ project(implement in VS6.0), and now I'd like to open it in VS2008 but I don't want to use .NET library because the application will be installed on the machine that has no any .NET framework (and I don't want to install any .NET to that machine).

So is it possible to do that in VS2008? is there any configuration in VS2008?

Thanks

Comment: Could you clarify your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you should need to do anything special.  If you open a C++ project from VC6 in Visual Studio 2008, it will convert the project.  But it won't build a .NET application.  It may require the CRT associated with VS2008, but it shouldn't need the .NET framework.

Comment: Mark is correct, MSVC++ in VS2008 will build a non .NET application.  Opening your VS6 project in VS2008 will create a project that does not rely on the .NET framework.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio supports both native C++ applications and .NET applications with C++